# Bigquery Streaming API (insertAll) takes too long to come back with a response

Tags: google-bigquery

We have been using the new Streaming API introduced by Google into their BigQuery engine for some of our internal stuff. The streaming response takes < 1 second on 99% of the requests but for a few requests, it takes around 15-16 minutes.

API method call : 'insertAll()'
Project_ID : '513990544911'

Co-incidentally, the response is always between 930-950 seconds. The request succeeds eventually and we get the expected response.

Has someone experienced similar problems and has been able to solve it? Can someone from the BigQuery team explain this behavior?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The BigQuery team helped me narrow it down and it was more of an issue on the client request side. 
The behavior was observed as I wasn't refreshing the service object used to make requests to BigQuery. 
Recreating the service object every now and then has stopped this issue to resurface.

**API : BigQuery Python API**

```
#Refresh service object in Python:
http = httplib2.Http()        
http = credentials.authorize(http)        
service = build('bigquery', 'v2', http=http)
```

The BigQuery support ticket : https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=196